# Decode: eval(stripslashes(gzinflate

Tags: php, decode

I can't seem to decode this base64 string which is in the footer of a wordpress theme. I want to be able to add more to the footer.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
<?php eval(stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("fZHBasMwDIbvhb6DyGHtLs19zRIoY9tte4BAsRMlNjiWScSyvP0Ur3iFlvliR/ry/+JXVRZ5a7/K7aaQCxqnpum5zhryjJ41MdNQZwm6YLYVpiNiHKW53UA6Dw2F5QiFAjNiJ1RRBRMAG0PQI58psCW/r3eGBqx3j0eoyrzOgC07TLh21FvfkXBeJW6d4592kasSXnCyvccW9HI1hGEOT3nejYi9/DAdhu8rz1cpw9taF4e/j6hnPTTknNI0qnVymC2bW2U9kHfWX9SbNbMk/+nUAlH2IzLJ6n4j2irf3prM83zQOLFBZyVmCT/ZXUd4EgTeE5Ps7tZXN1lqWq+8Y8RzOP/udx+zXRFN7RIfhgcnm/gB")))); ?>

<?php eval(stripslashes(gzinflate(base64_decode("fZHBSsQwEIbvgu8w9OCul+3drS0sot70AQJL0kybQJoJbbD27Z1GjYVdzCWTyZ//C/80dVVq+1Hf3vzuXHEBVj+KoiOKOIqC25DXXUthOUIlwYzYsapqggmArSHoMZ4pREt+L3aGBhS7+yM0dSkKiDY6zHLlqLe+I9Z5mXWM+u+6KmUNTzjZ3qMGtWw+YWIMD2XZjYg9P5gOw+eG+cxteFn7TPg7JD/roSXnpKJRrj+H2UZz6awG8s76H/eWho39u5MLJNu3pMmo6xcJK72+hMzzfFA4RYPOcswcfsZtIzyxBF6zJuOu9lfadrxcp4jncP6e7z5lu0oU6SUVJg6OJ/EF")))); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Switch `eval` to `print` and it'll show you what the encoded text entails. They're doing it like this, presumably, to prevent you from removing their "Free Games" spammy links.

```
?></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
          &copy; <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a> Designed by <a href="http://freegames.mx" title="Free Games">Free Games</a> in collaboration with <a href="http://bmonlinegames.com" title="Play Free Online Games">Play Free Online Games</a> and <a href="http://www.besthelicoptergames.com/" title="Best Helicopter Games">Best Helicopter Games</a>
</div>


<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```