# Site hacked, who wants to figure out what this encoded string says (ROT13, eval, base64_decode, and gzinflate used)?

Tags: php

In several files, I found injected code in my PHP files.  I attempted to Pastebin the code, but Pastebin actually wouldn't accept the code. I tried various Pastebin alternatives as well, none of them would accept the code as-is, not even StackOverflow.

So what I've done is uploaded the to my own personal server and am hosting it from a *.txt file.  If someone knows a better way, please let me know. I know it seems fishy (at least, my actions seem fishy even to me) and I apologize for that.

Also, there are three "paragraphs" of code, each paragraph was found on a different page, injected at the top of all 3. The first block of code is rather small, only about 5 or so lines after wordwrap.  The other two blocks of code are quite lengthy, and in the 3rd block of code exists a 4th inline encoded string.

The injected code:

http://184.172.138.95/~smgwebd/code.txt

Comment: There's not many safe ways to determine what the code actually is, without running it. :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122642/help-me-to-decode-evalstripslashesgzinflate

Comment: Remove eval and output the contents of the string.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the calls to `eval` with `echo` instead? That may help you at least see what is being executed.

Comment: [First two parts decoded](http://pastebin.com/X8mY18SD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After expanding the first line, I noticed that there is a little file upload form that they put in there, with this Copyright...

```
Copyright 2011 by kaMtiEz - MagelangCyber Team ! d0nt rem0ve copyright if u real hax0r
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `eval` command with an `echo` and look at the resulting string.

Having looked at the first entry it expands to another encoded string.  Repeating the process - i.e. taking the resulting string from the first entry and again swapping the `eval` for `echo` reveals the code.